# Styling a 'title' attribute with CSS or possible alternatives?

Tags: html, css, title

I've made a small image gallery with 'Image Thumbnail Viewer 2' [Link here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/thumbnail2.htm)

script allows title attribute below image that is expanded. Everything works fine but I cannot find a way to style the text in the title attribute.

All i want to do is change some basic features i.e. font-family, font-size, margin etc. nothing fancy.

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="img/test%20images/IMG305eng.jpg" 
           rel="enlargeimage"  
           rev="targetdiv:main,trigger:click,preload:yes,fx:fade" 
           title="&lt;em&gt;Hello World&lt;/em&gt; - 2014 - 20x30x5cm">
           <img src="img/test%20images/IMG305eng.jpg">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

above is an example of one image thumbnail

Each image will will need a different caption underneath it. not sure if its worth using the title attribute or just doing it another way entirely.

Thanks - second post on stack-overflow so let me know if i'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: Try this selector in CSS: `#loadarea div {color: red;}`

Comment: You need to target the markup (HTML) that the plugin generates as @Aziz has pointed out.

Comment: The `title` attribute does not take HTML, and is not stylable.

Comment: thanks! that got it... can't believe i was staring at the for an hour trying all manner of complicated fixes... cheers for the help!

Comment: as torazaburo points out, normally the title attribute  is not stylable, but libraries like Jquery do make use of them and do/can apply styles via javascript, such as..  https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

The real question is, if you are using a library like Jquery, what is the CSS selector for "title" to apply your styles to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the markup (HTML) that the plugin generates as @Aziz has pointed out.

Your text (when hovering an image) is contained in an element with the ID of `#loadedarea`.

```css
#loadedarea {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @RST I mentioned **Aziz** in the answer. If he comes back and answers great. But in case he doesn't there's an actual answer to the question posted. Get off your high horse.

Comment: Ok everybody chill. I don't mind. Credit is nice but ultimately the emphasis should be on the solution rather than the person because that's what really matters. Enjoy the rest of your day/night!

Answer (score 1):

you may need to modify the js script to insert a specific tag :
example: instead `<br/>` i added a `<p>` https://jsfiddle.net/x7w12etr/2/ (fixed and updated fiddle)

modified: *(notice that you can add a class or id to this extra tag holding the alt attribute value of image)*

```
 if (setting.link)
            imghtml='<a href="'+setting.link+'">'+imghtml+'</a>'
        imghtml='<div>'+imghtml+((setting.enabletitle!='no' && $anchor.attr('title')!='')? '<p>'+$anchor.attr('title') : '')+'</p></div>'
        return $(imghtml)
    }
```

From here you can target that `p` with css .

---

original:

```
if (setting.link)
            imghtml='<a href="'+setting.link+'">'+imghtml+'</a>'
        imghtml='<div>'+imghtml+((setting.enabletitle!='no' && $anchor.attr('title')!='')? '<br />'+$anchor.attr('title') : '')+'</div>'
        return $(imghtml)
    },
```

Comment: this will offer better control. I'd recommend it if OP wants to add advanced CSS rules.